# Automorphisms of rational curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a non-empty open subscheme of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$.

What is the automorphism group of $X$ in terms of PGL$_n(\mathbb C)$ and the points on the boundary?

Comment: The automorphism group is the subgroup of $PGL_2$ preserving the finite set $\mathbf P^1 \setminus X$. Is that the kind of answer you want?